# AHK: How to change window transparency when window is not active?

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I would like to change the GUI to transparent when the window is not active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in the beginning of the code:

```
OnMessage(0x06, "WM_ACTIVATE") ;TRIGGER FUNCTION WHEN WINDOW'S ACTIVE STATUS IS CHANGED
```

Add this function to your code:

```
WM_ACTIVATE()
{
    IfWinActive, MyWindow
        WinSet, Transparent, 255, MyWindow ; TRANSPARENCY OFF
    else
        WinSet, Transparent, 200, MyWindow ; SET TRANSPARENCY BETWEEN 0-255
}
```